# boot parameters seems not to work with ipxe and daily image

Tags: pxe, preseed, kernel-parameters

I am trying to auto install debian buster with ipxe, it seems that the boot parameters don't work in the ipxe menu. I always get the language section. So the preseed isn't loaded. Here is the relevant entry in the ipxe menu:

```
:d10-dc-node
set base-url https://d-i.debian.org/daily-images/amd64/daily/netboot/debian-installer/amd64
kernel ${base-url}/linux
initrd ${base-url}/initrd.gz
imgargs linux vga=normal root=/dev/ram rw preseed/url=tftp://my.ipxe.server/preseed/debian_buster_node.seed netcfg/choose_interface=eno1 debian-installer/framebuffer=false debian-installer/locale=en_US kbd-chooser/method=us auto-install/enable=true debconf/frontend=noninteractive debconf/priority=critical console-setup/ask_detect=false keyboard-configuration/modelcode=pc105 keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us keyboard-configuration/variant=USA hostname=ubuntu ---
```

and here is the preseed part:

```
### Keyboard
d-i                 console-setup/ask_detect                        boolean                 false
d-i                 keyboard-configuration/layout                   select                  USA
d-i                 keyboard-configuration/variant                  select                  USA
d-i                 keyboard-configuration/modelcode                string                  pc105
d-i                 keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap               select                  en
d-i                 keyboard-configuration/layout                   string                  English

### Locales
d-i                 debian-installer/country                        string                  DE
d-i                 debian-installer/language                       string                  en
d-i                 debian-installer/locale                         string                  en_US.UTF-8
d-i                 localechooser/supported-locales                 multiselect             en_US.UTF-8, de_DE.UTF-8
```

When I try to set the base-url to `http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/amd64` it works fine until loading the modules, then I get the following error: `"No kernel modules were found"`, which I guess because of the different Kernel versions.

Comment: I acheived to pass the kernel parameters after changing them to `imgargs linux auto preseed/url=tftp://my.ipxe.server/preseed/debian_buster_node.seed netcfg/choose_interface=eno1 auto-install/enable=true fb=false debconf/frontend=noninteractive debian-installer=en_US.UTF-8 auto locale=en_US.UTF-8 console-setup/ask_detect=false kbd-chooser/method=us keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=us keyboard-configuration/modelcode=pc105 keyboard-configuration/layout=USA keyboard-configuration/variant=USA BOOT_DEBUG=2 --` the only problem I still have is that the preseed is not being loaded!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could install debian buster fully unattended by using the following Kernel arguments:

```
:d10-dc-node
set base-url https://d-i.debian.org/daily-images/amd64/daily/netboot/debian- 
installer/amd64
kernel ${base-url}/linux
initrd ${base-url}/initrd.gz
initrd tftp://my.ipxe.server/preseed/debian_buster_node.seed /tmp/debian_buster_node.seed
imgargs linux auto vga=normal root=/dev/ram rw file=/tmp/debian_buster_node.seed interface=eno1 fb=false debian-installer=en_US.UTF-8 locale=en_US.UTF-8 kbd-chooser/method=us auto-install/enable=true debconf/frontend=noninteractive priority=critical console-setup/ask_detect=false keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=us keyboard-configuration/modelcode=pc105 keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us keyboard-configuration/variant=USA ---
boot
```

Network configuration and hostname will be set with DHCP.

Thanks